# Form - action attribute

Tags: python, django

I want to create an "index.html" Django template, which contains a button. When the button is pressed, I want to render the template "home.html", which itself displays the value "123". (Of course, there is a simpler way to do this specific task - but I am learning Django and so want to try it this way.)

Here is my views.py file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def home(request, x)
    context = {'x': x}
    return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

Here is my urls.py file:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from myapp import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
url(r'^home', views.home, name='home'),
)
```

Here is my home.html file:

```
<html>
<body>
The value is: {{ x }}
</body>
</html>
```

Finally, here is my index.html file:

```
<html>
<form method="post" action=???>
<input type="button" value="Click Me">
</form>
```

Please can somebody tell me what I need to write in place of the ???, in the action attribute above? I have tried setting ??? = "{% url 'home' 123 %}" but this gives me a "NoReverseMatch" error. Therefore, I suspect there may be also be something wrong with my urls.py file...

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite your index.html like this

```
<html>
<form method="post" action=/home>
<input type="hidden" name="my_value" value="123">
<input type="button" value="Click Me">
</form>
```

It contains a hidden variable called `my_value` its hold your value `123`. And i your view.py accept this value like this,

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def home(request)
    x = ' '
    if request.POST:
        x = request.POST['my_value']
    context = {'x': x}
    return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the NoReverseMatch error because you do not have a url that captures the 123 that you send along with the url. Let me tell you an easy way:

You can set the action as something like:

```
action="/home/123" # or any integer you wish to send.
```

And match that url in urls py by modifying the home url as:

```
url(r'^home/(?P<x>\d+)/$', views.home, name='home')
```

This passes whatever parameter you send in the home url(which should be an integer in this case) as x. Thus the x will be displayed in the home.html